# Weak convergence in $H_0^1$ and strong convergence in $L^2$

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, real-analysis

I'm reading a hand-waving argument in a proof of Chapter 7 of *Navier–Stokes Equations* by Constantin and Foias. I would like to know if I understand it correctly.

Let $\Omega\subset{\mathbb{R}^n}$ be an open set with $\partial \Omega$ being $C^k$, $k\geq 2$.
Let $\mathcal{V}$ be the space

$$\displaystyle \mathcal{V}=\{u\in C_0^\infty(\Omega)\mid \nabla\cdot u=0\}.$$

Let
$
H=\overline{\mathcal{V}}^{\lVert\cdot\rVert_{L^2(\Omega)^n}}
$
and
$
V=\overline{\mathcal{V}}^{\lVert\cdot\rVert_{H_0^1(\Omega)^n}}.
$

Is the following statement true?

> Suppose $u_m\to u$ weakly in $V$. Then there exists a subsequence $u_{m'}\to u$ strongly in $H$.

Comment: I think this would be true if the inclusion from $V$ into $H$ is a compact linear map

Comment: Weak boundedness implies strong boundedness...

Comment: It is true if $\Omega$ is bounded, since then $H^1_0$ imbeds compactly into $L^2$.

Comment: @paulgarrett: Thanks for your comment. A quick search on Google for "Weak boundedness implies strong boundedness" returns your lecture notes on Functional Analysis. Are you saying that "$u_m$ converges weakly in $V$" implies it is weakly bounded and thus by the theorem in your note, it is strongly bounded in $H$? With this argument, it seems that one does not need the assumption that $\Omega$ is bounded?

Comment: Jack, indeed, weak convergence of a sequence implies that the sequence, as a set, is weakly bounded, hence bounded. But bounded does not imply _compact_. This weak-to-strong trick is just a frequently helpful little extra fact. The key point is the compactness, as @MichaelRenardy notes.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is correct.
since $u_m \to u$  weakly in V, so $u_m$ is bounded ,then (by the compact embedding theorem) $H$ can be embedding $V$,thus $u_{{m}^{\prime}} \to u $ strongly in $H$.